# discord.py NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, interaction

```
@bot.tree.command(name="clear", description="admin only", guild=discord.Object(guildid))
async def clear(interaction: discord.Interaction, amount : int = None):
     if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
         return
     if amount == None:
         embed = discord.Embed(title="** Error**", description=f"Please enter the amount to be deleted",color=0xff0000, timestamp = datetime.datetime.now())
         await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
     else:
         await interaction.channel.purge(limit=amount)
         embed = discord.Embed(title="** Chat Cleaning **", description=f"{amount} recent chats have been deleted", color = 0xFFFD05, timestamp = datetime.datetime.now())
         await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
         await asyncio. sleep(2)
         await interaction.channel.purge(limit=1)
```

```
  File "C:\Users\Heeryun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1242, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Heeryun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 887, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
  File "C:\Users\Heeryun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 880, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'clear' raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction
```

clear system
I think it is interaction error
The message is deleted, but an error occurs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

This happens when you're too slow to respond to an interaction. You must always respond within **3 seconds** or your interaction will fail.

If you need more than 3 seconds, you can use `defer()`, and then reply using `followup`.

Considering the fact that you're purging messages before replying, you won't be in time anymore. You should **first** defer, then do what you want, and then send the follow-up message.

Note that you can only respond once. You *have to* use followup (or `channel.send`) for consecutive messages or it will error as well.

Also:

- instead of deleting the message manually after 2 seconds, you can make it ephemeral (so only the user can see it, and they can manually dismiss it).
- the first if-statement will never send a response, so it will always cause an error in Discord. It's better to send an actual error message to the user instead of letting the command fail. You can once again make it ephemeral.
- use `is` instead of `==` for `None`-checks

Answer (score 0):

You're not deferring your code.

Slash commands are terminated after 3 seconds from the time the command was used. This means that if you don't make the API interaction (the slash command) respond in some way, Discord will disconnect that specific interaction.

To avoid this, you need to make the command respond with the `defer()` method. Deferring delays that termination, giving your code more time to run.

Ideally, you'd wanna defer the code before anything else like so:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="clear", description="admin only", guild=discord.Object(guildid))
async def clear(interaction: discord.Interaction, amount : int = None):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    #rest of your code
```